# Python execution via the Polyglot API always needs full System IO access

Tags: graalvm

I am trying to execute some very straightforward piece of python code via the polyglot API. When trying to run even simple tests such as the following:

```
@Test
public void printSomTextPythonTest() throws ScriptExecutionException, IOException {

    String code = "print('Python will print this to the console!')";    

    String[] supportedLangs = { "js", "python", "R" };

    Context testContext = Context.newBuilder(supportedLangs)
            .allowAllAccess(false)
            .allowHostAccess(false)
            .allowHostClassLoading(false)
            .allowIO(false)
            .allowNativeAccess(false)
            .allowCreateThread(false)               
            .build();

    Source source = Source.newBuilder("python", code, "pyScript").build();              
    Value result = testContext.eval(source);

    testContext.close();
}
```

Or:

```
@Test
public void setAVariablePythonTest() throws ScriptExecutionException, IOException {

    String code = "someNumber = 11";

    String[] supportedLangs = { "js", "python", "R" };

    Context testContext = Context.newBuilder(supportedLangs)
            .allowAllAccess(false)
            .allowHostAccess(false)
            .allowHostClassLoading(false)
            .allowIO(false)
            .allowNativeAccess(false)
            .allowCreateThread(false)               
            .build();

    Source source = Source.newBuilder("python", code, "pyScript").build();              
    Value result = testContext.eval(source);

    testContext.close();
}
```

I get this error (stack trace below):

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.SecurityException: Operation is not allowed for: /code/polyglot-test
```

If I change allowIO to true when building the Context, the code runs fine and gives the expected result. I have also tried it with more complex code with the same results.

Why is IO access necessary for Python code to be executed?

Equivalent code written and executed in JS does not need the allowIO to be set to true, so it seems to me to be a Python specific thing.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I have been testing with R as a guest language too. Running the following test:

```
@Test
public void helloWorldRTest() throws ScriptExecutionException, IOException {

    String code = "print(\"R will print this to the console!\")";       

    String[] supportedLangs = { "js", "python", "R" };

    Context testContext = Context.newBuilder(supportedLangs)
            .allowAllAccess(false)
            .allowHostAccess(false)
            .allowHostClassLoading(false)
            .allowIO(false)
            .allowNativeAccess(false)
            .allowCreateThread(false)               
            .build();

    Source source = Source.newBuilder("R", code, "rScript").build();                
    Value result = testContext.eval(source);

    testContext.close();
}
```

I get the following error:

*FastR unexpected failure: error loading libR from: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/R/lib/libR.dylib.
If running on the NFI backend, did you provide the location of libtrufflenfi.so as the value of the system property 'truffle.nfi.library'?
The current value is 'null'.
Is the OpenMP runtime library (libgomp.so) present on your system? This library is, e.g., typically part of the GCC package.
Details: Access to native code is not allowed by the host environment.*

However, by setting "allowNativeAccess" to true, the code runs fine without errors.

Do different languages need different types of access priviliges to run?

In my use case I am trying to sandbox the execution as much as possible. I want the scripts, regardless of the language they are written in to only have access to the data that is given to them. 
Scripts running in the guest languages should not have any access to the host system. Is this achievable?

**Partial stack trace** (if needed for debugging I can supply the full stack trace):

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.SecurityException: Operation is not allowed for: /code/polyglot-test
    at com.oracle.truffle.api.vm.FileSystems$DeniedIOFileSystem.forbidden(FileSystems.java:489)
    at com.oracle.truffle.api.vm.FileSystems$DeniedIOFileSystem.checkAccess(FileSystems.java:367)
    at com.oracle.truffle.api.TruffleFile.checkAccess(TruffleFile.java:983)
    at com.oracle.truffle.api.TruffleFile.exists(TruffleFile.java:102)
    at com.oracle.graal.python.builtins.modules.PosixModuleBuiltins$StatNode.stat(PosixModuleBuiltins.java:404)
    at com.oracle.graal.python.builtins.modules.PosixModuleBuiltins$StatNode.doStat(PosixModuleBuiltins.java:397)
    at com.oracle.graal.python.builtins.modules.PosixModuleBuiltinsFactory$StatNodeFactory$StatNodeGen.executeAndSpecialize(PosixModuleBuiltinsFactory.java:855)
    at com.oracle.graal.python.builtins.modules.PosixModuleBuiltinsFactory$StatNodeFactory$StatNodeGen.execute(PosixModuleBuiltinsFactory.java:807)
    at com.oracle.graal.python.nodes.function.BuiltinFunctionRootNode$BuiltinBinaryCallNode.execute(BuiltinFunctionRootNode.java:103)
    at com.oracle.graal.python.nodes.function.BuiltinFunctionRootNode.execute(BuiltinFunctionRootNode.java:229)
    at  stat(Unknown)
    at  stat(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-graalpython/posix.py:51:2230-2247)
    at  _path_stat(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:82:2759-2772)
    at  _path_is_mode_type(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:88:2901-2916)
    at  _path_isdir(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:103:3245-3278)
    at  path_hook_for_FileFinder(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:1333:50397-50413)
    at  PathFinder._path_hooks(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:1083:40517-40526)
    at  PathFinder._path_importer_cache(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:1107:41279-41299)
    at  PathFinder._get_spec(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:1135:42391-42421)
    at  PathFinder.find_spec(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py:1166:43686-43722)
    at  _find_spec(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap.py:892:28932-28960)
    at  _find_and_load_unlocked(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap.py:953:31192-31213)
    at  _find_and_load(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap.py:968:31701-31738)
    at  _gcd_import(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap.py:985:32285-32317)
    at  **import**(../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-python/3/importlib/_bootstrap.py:1066:35366-35382)
    at  (../../../../../Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ee-1.0.0-rc4/Contents/Home/jre/languages/python/lib-graalpython/**builtins_patches**.py:48:2220-2224)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:313)
    at bolt.tests.BoltEngineGraalTest.helloWorldPythonTest(BoltEngineGraalTest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Original Internal Error: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Operation is not allowed for: /code/polyglot-test
    at com.oracle.truffle.api.vm.FileSystems$DeniedIOFileSystem.forbidden(FileSystems.java:489)
    at com.oracle.truffle.api.vm.FileSystems$DeniedIOFileSystem.checkAccess(FileSystems.java:367)
...

Comment: Note that by default, no accesses are granted, so just `Context.newBuilder(supportedLangs).build()` is equivalent.

Comment: I think this might have to do with native extensions. If a language requires native extensions to, for example, print to console than it needs native access given.

Comment: @eregon indeed you are right. I wrote it out to make the example more explicit

Comment: @BoriS I am suspecting that could be the case. Also looking at the pring-R graal example, I can see that they enable allAccess. https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-demos/blob/master/spring-r/src/main/java/org/graalvm/demos/springr/SpringRApplication.java What does it mean exactly to allow native access? The docs are not very specific **Allows guest languages to access the native interface.** I am worried that this might mean that not all languages can be entirely sandboxed from the host...